# Bingo Board: Generating unique values

Tags: c++, random, unique, srand

I'm having trouble generating unique values which do NOT repeat for this bingo board. My code is relatively simple: I use a nested for loop to generate the values with some print statements; upon each nested iteration, I check to see if the value generated exists within the array. If it exists, it returns true, and the generated value selects a new random number. I thought that by initiating srand() upon each iteration, and using the count in the loop as its seed, I would be able to achieve this. Unfortunately, It doesn't seem very possible.

How is this achieved?

My code:

```
#define MAX 100
#define MIN 1

using std::vector;

bool Board::checkValues(unsigned int array[], unsigned int valueToCheck)
{
    int len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);

    bool numberExists = false;

    static int repeatCount = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (valueToCheck == array[i])
        {
            numberExists = true;
            repeatCount++;
            break;
        }
    }

    return numberExists;
}

Board::Board(unsigned int numberOfRows, unsigned int numberOfColumns)
{
    this->numRows = numberOfRows;
    this->numColumns = numberOfColumns;

    for (int i = 0; i < this->numRows; i++)
    {
        this->board.push_back(vector<unsigned int>(this->numColumns, 0));
    }

    this->valuesVisited[numberOfRows * numberOfColumns];
}

void Board::generate()
{
    int repeatCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < this->numRows; i++)
    {
        bool atMid = false;

        if (i == this->numRows / 2 - 1)
        {
            atMid = true;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < this->numColumns; j++)
        {
            if (atMid && j == this->numColumns / 2 - 1)
            {
                printf(" Free ");
                continue;
            }

            int seed = (i + 1) * (j + 1);

            unsigned int randNumber = generateRand(MIN, MAX, seed);

            bool numberExists = checkValues(this->valuesVisited, randNumber);

            if (numberExists)
            {
                //int equation = (randNumber % 10) + (i * j) / (randNumber + randNumber);

                randNumber = generateRand(MIN, MAX, seed) - (i * j);
                repeatCount++;
            }

            this->valuesVisited[(i + 1) * (j + 1)] = randNumber;

            this->board[i][j] = randNumber;

            printf(" %d ", board[i][j]);
        }

        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }

    printf("You have %d repeats", repeatCount);
}
```

Comment: are you looking for a random generator without repeats? why don't just make a ransom permutation, and then choose elements iteratively?

Answer (score 2):

Consider filling a `std::vector` with the candidate numbers, then perform a `std::random_shuffle` on it and take the first N.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach I use for this "generate n unique random numbers" is to fill a vector with the total range of numbers (for you here, MIN -> MAX), random_shuffle() that and then just pull as many values as I need from the front that. I think there are probably slightly more efficient ways if performance is ultra-critical, but it seems to do pretty well in all the situations I've needed so far.

Something like

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int index = MIN;
std::generate_n(back_inserter(numbers), MAX - MIN + 1,
    [&](){return index++;});

std::random_shuffle(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

for(int i = 0; i < this->numRows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < this->numColumns; j++)
    {
        this->board[i][j] = numbers.back();
        numbers.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you have efficiency concerns, you can always avoid poping the values from the `vector` at all, and keep an index or iterator to the next number instead.

Comment: +1 for using `std::random_shuffle`. ( I would suggest you to prefix it with `std::`, as it indicates where `random_shuffle` come from).

Comment: I'm not quite following this bit, here: generate_n(back_inserter(numbers), MAX - MIN + 1,
    [&](){return index++;});
Would you mind explaining to me how the return value (in an argument???) works?

Comment: @Holland: `[&](){return index++;}` is a C++11 lambda, the lambda function is the argument.

Comment: @Holland: That's a new C++11 lambda. It's basically a a little mini-function. In this case, what it does is simply return the next counting number every time it's called. That whole generate statement is equivalent to `for (int num = MIN; num <= MAX; ++num) numbers.push_back(num);`

Comment: @K-ballo: I'm just not sure that doing a full random_shuffle just to generate a unique sequence of random numbers seems a tad overkill for this. Still, it's easy and it's never been a perf concern for me so I've never really looked into alternatives!

Comment: @Ayjay: how would you go about it to make it more efficient? You'll always _need_ to have O(n) storage requirements in the end, or you couldn't guarantee non-repeating output.

Comment: @sehe: Well, getting this down to O(n) would be a nice start! The naive method generates more elements than it needs to. As for a way of getting more efficient than that, I don't know. I am no expert in mathematics, but I wouldn't be surprised if there was a function that could generate a pseudorandom cycle for a specified number of elements. That would not require any storage, merely repeated applications of that function. Or maybe that function doesn't exist not - like I said, I haven't really looked into it much.

Comment: @Ayjay: A random sequence is _flawed_ if you know it can't repeat itself! It's just that the chance of it repeating should be predictable (low, normally), not absent. In truly random, 'abc' should be about as likely as 'aaa' (as long as it is (a) not predictable (b) has normal distribution - depending on the flavour of randomness). Actually, this question has _very little_ to do with random number generation. It has to do with _random selection_ which _is_ a sorting operation. _PS. I also hope you spotted where I said O(n) >storage< requirement_

Comment: Is O(n) supposed to represent a function of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

This is some code I came up with for my little project

Nothing fancy but it generates unique numbers and for me it filled a need.

```
for (int a = 0; a <= 89; a++) //populate the array with numbers 1-90
{
    bNumbers[a].Number = a + 1;
}
for (int a = 0; a < bNumbers.Length; a++) //swap positions of the generated numbers
{
    int rBingo = bMain.rndNum.Next(a, bNumbers.Length); //generate random number
    // swap numbers round in the array
    int tmpNum = bNumbers.Number;
    bNumbers.Number = bNumbers[rBingo].Number;
    bNumbers[rBingo].Number = tmpNum;
    //end of swap                 
}
```